# Visual studio internal ts compiler doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript

I searched many and also applied these:
`"Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets"` to .csproj file

The key is, I am already working on app which I've created via `angular-cli` here is `tsconfig` file content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

So I tried to use same configurations for Visual Studio project then 
edited `TypesciptBuild` section in project properties, here how it looks like:
[image]

I expect to see generated `js` files in Scripts directory but when I saved (`ts`) file, it didn't work. 
I think the problem is root directory here, because none of the libraries seem to be accessible by `ts` file. However, nothing seems wrong at all. What should I do? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

plz checkout mine article to successfully setting up angular2 + typescript in VS2015 here. And no need to run node.js or any command line commands for development purpose

https://github.com/MohtishamZubair/AgentDistribution/wiki/Setting-up-AngularJS2-in-VS2015-in-MVC5

do checkout the tsconfig.json & package.json files in zip

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio should read from the tsconfig.json file that is included in your project.  So manually setting values in the `<TypescriptBuild>` section might not be doing anything.

I think your problem is that you are setting `typeRoots` in your tsconfig.json.  This will cause the ts compiler to look in that defined folder for all types.  The Angular types exist under `node_modules/@angular/*` and not under `node_modules/@types` so that is probably why you're getting those errors. Because you set `moduleResolution` to `node`, it will by default look up any types that exist under `node_modules` which is where all the Angular types exist and any global types specified in `node_modules/@types`.  So removing `typeRoots` might fix some of your problems.